# database and php debugger

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was wondering whether there is a tool available that one can use to debug their database and php applications. Equivalent of firebug or chrome developer extension for databases and php. (I would like to know whether some queries are executed or not exected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or a similar extension to debug PHP, in addition to the traditional `var_dump` and similar techniques.

Turn on [query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) to debug what your database does or doesn't do.
To debug individual query execution, have the database [`EXPLAIN` the queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to you.

Answer (score 1):

[PhpEd](http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=CYQPZkbuhT872LYa2iAKkg-TNCqf1htEBp9Cdyhinv-K8EQgAEAFQ-eLRqgNgyZ7EjfSk0BmgAYLIh_8DyAEBqgQWT9CJsZqOFiCSmWnMmSWymuJIF9gwaQ&sig=AOD64_2lJGXXSEEZk40imN7ECsUWTRX7Ng&ved=0CAoQ0Qw&adurl=http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm&rct=j&q=phped%20nusphere) is awesome!  Can hardly get out of bed without it these days, lol